# SUMO tracefile mobility with ns3

Tags: sumo, ns-3

I'm trying to include a SUMO generated mobility (I generated the file mobility.tcl) into ns3 but it doesn't work and I got this error
cond="!(0 != model)", msg="node 0 does not have a MobilityModel", file=../src/buildings/helper/buildings-helper.cc, line=53

Ps: I have followed ns2-mobility-trace.cc  and https://www.opensourceforu.com/2017/11/tracing-vehicular-mobility-ns-3/
Can you help me, please

Answer (score 0):

Please see NS-3 mobility models docs for how to install the custom models

https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/mobility.html#ns-2-mobilityhelper